# How to make menu appear from left for mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have web site that display username and image at the top right corner.
I use `media query` to detect mobile device and then I hide that and display only `user image`.
Now I am trying to make that when user tap on that image to menu appear from the right like on google.
[image]
I have tried to follow few examples but I don't understand when to use only css or css + js can somebody explain me what is the way to make this?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
This code should put overlay menu over content:

```
$('.accountImageMobile').click(function () {
                $('#over-menu').css({ left: '0' });
            });
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="topHeader" style="background: #f5f5f5; min-height: 42px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5PX;">
            ...
<img id="accountImageMobile" style="max-width: 45px;" src="image.jpg" alt="" />
...
</div> >>>>top  header  end

        <div id="over-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
...
```

But when I open site on mobile device it shows the list bellow top header...

Comment: Did you forgot to close the header with `</header>`

Comment: No all tags are closed. But when I detect mobile screen I just set `over-menu` with `display: block` and `background: #ff0000`. Do I need to set it some other `css` to not show it until user tap on image?

Comment: I've updated my answer...try with that...and don't put `display: block;` on div, div is displayed block by default, unless you show/hide it with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/vLwjX/)

```
#over-menu {
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

$(function() {
  $('#accountImageMobile').click(function () {
     $('#over-menu').css({ left: '0' });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/) is an awesome and easy-to-use JS library for doing just this. One thing to be careful of though: iOS 7 is using edge swipe gestures across the board which may interfere with any mobile UIs you work on. Just a note. You can disable swipe though, just triggering the menu from a button if you wish.

Comment: I am trying to make this without plugins.